# ModX: Selecting and outputting specific menu items using Wayfinder

Tags: modx

I've been trying to output specific menu items, also wanting to change the names of some, without satisfying results. The problem is that I have three different menu setups throughout the site - the header split into two sections and the footer divided into a couple of columns. This is what I've tried so far -


`[[Wayfinder? &startId=0 &level=1 &limit=5 &excludeDocs=49,61,55]]`


While it works excluding all the other links isn't the most optimal solution as there are 11 in total plus I want to be able to 1. rearrange the order and 2. change the names of two of them.
Is this possible at all using the Wayfinder or do I have to create a snippet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names *(menu title)* and Order *(Menu Index)* - you control via the manager interface *(or Doc Manager module for quicker order sorting)*.

This is the default,  you can also customize this (textOfLinks, sortBy, sortOrder)
About excludeDocs,  maybe using the opposite - includeDocs param is better for you.

see this: [www.muddydogpaws.com/development/wayfinder/parameters.html](http://www.muddydogpaws.com/development/wayfinder/parameters.html)

Comment: Sorry this post hasn't been updated, found a solution a couple of weeks ago.